# what is 'code' parameter in django-rest-social-auth?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-auth

I am new in Django and working on **django-rest-social-auth**.

I want to implement social login in my app.(frontend- angular, Backend- Django)

but I am not getting what is the **code** parameter below request.

```
POST /api/login/social/token/
```

input:

```
 {
      "provider": "facebook",
      "code": "AQBPBBTjbdnehj51"
  }
```

output:

{
      "token": "68ded41d89f6a28da050f882998b2ea1decebbe0"
  }

```
POST /api/login/social/token_user/
```

input:

```
{
      "provider": "facebook",
      "code": "AQBPBBTjbdnehj51"
  }
```

output:

```
  {
      "username": "Alex",
      "email": "user@email.com",
      // other user data
      "token": "68ded41d89f6a28da050f882998b2ea1decebbe0"
  }
```

Comment: see [this](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.1)

Comment: thank you Yug, But ho do I get this 'code'? what is the steps to get this code?

Comment: I would suggest reading documentation properly for implementing see this is quotes here `To have a resource, that will do very simple thing: take the oauth code from social provider (for example facebook) and return the authenticated user. That's it.`